# Square waves in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a problem in sympy with outputing mathematical functions with different calculations for different cases. For example I want to make a function like a saw wave.(1 if -1 < x <1 else 0)

I would like to define a function in a

```
f = x**2 + 1
```

like way to make a function that acts like

```
f = 1 if -1 < x < 1 else 0
```

Comment: [sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise)

Answer (score 0):

Found a page you might be interested in http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/sets.html but you don't specify your problem particularly well. If you could provide some code, what you have tried, stuff like that would make it easier for us to help.